# Intellij plugin development print in console window

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, window, action

I am new to Intellij Idea plugin development.  So I am developing a simple plugin to print a string value in a tool window(similar to console window)! There are less examples when I searched the web! I have a slight understanding about the Intellij action system but is unable to figure out how to register the necessary action in the plugin.xml  to print the string in a tool window!

Following is my code

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;

    public class A extends AnAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
           String x="Hello how are you?";
        }
    }
```

How can I print String x in a tool window?

Comment: Which tool window? Is your action even triggered?

Comment: @Meo No! I dont know how to register action for the tool window and which method to call in the class A to print string x

Comment: Which tool window, where exactly do you want that action? ...read intellij-sources and find something similar.

Comment: @Meo I want to have something like a console when I run the plugin and print the value of string x in it! eg-showMessageDialog() can be used to print the string in a dialog box but instead I need a something like a console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console windows can't just exist on their own, they have to be tied to a tool window. Here's a quick example.

First create a ToolWindow for your plugin in XML:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
  <!-- Add your extensions here -->
  <toolWindow id="MyPlugin" 
              anchor="bottom"
              icon="iconfile.png"
              factoryClass="com.intellij.execution.dashboard.RunDashboardToolWindowFactory"></toolWindow>
</extensions>
```

Then in your action, you can grab a handle to that tool window and lazily create a console view, then add your text there:

```
  ToolWindow toolWindow = ToolWindowManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).getToolWindow("MyPlugin");
  ConsoleView consoleView = TextConsoleBuilderFactory.getInstance().createBuilder(e.getProject()).getConsole();
  Content content = toolWindow.getContentManager().getFactory().createContent(consoleView.getComponent(), "MyPlugin Output", false);
  toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
  consoleView.print("Hello from MyPlugin!", ConsoleViewContentType.NORMAL_OUTPUT);
```

A couple of notes:

1. Your new tool window may not be visible by default so you may need to activate it from the View -> Tool Windows menu.
2. We used `RunDashboardToolWindowFactory` to create our new tool window, so it will take on the layout of a run window. You can use any implementation of `ToolWindowFactory` (including your own custom class) in its place.

[image]

Comment: For reference:

Basic ToolWindow configuration:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/master/code_samples/tool_window
http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/user_interface_components/tool_windows.html

Coding the console view:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206756385-How-to-make-a-simple-console-output

Example plugin using custom tool window:

Comment: Thanx !  But I want to know whats the action type I have to use here?

Comment: @JohnSmith Not sure what you mean by action type. You could put the code above into the `actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e)` method of any of your registered actions.

Comment: Yeah I meant as what action I have to register in the plugin.xml

Comment: Depends on when you want your plugins to "run". Most actions are triggered by menus or buttons in the IDE, but you could also adapt the code to fire when an editor event happens: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics/editor_events.html

Comment: Thanx actually I want to do when an editor event happens what is the best action to use for that?

Comment: See the link in my last comment, it has some code samples for listening to keystrokes in an editor window and responding to them.

Comment: I checked it but most examples are with editor popup menu action! I just want to display tool window upon a key stroke

Comment: Mike, it's strange, but for me it doesn't work... Moreover after start IDEA with my plugin I have no "Run" in  "View -> Tool Windows" menu and It appears only after pushing the green button "Run" which looks like a play button... What do I do wrong?

Comment: Does there need to be an icon in order for it to work?

Comment: `RunDashboardToolWindowFactory` class not found exception

Answer (score 1):

`RunDashboardToolWindowFactory` no longer exists in the lastest intellij-community codebase. The only reference I have is https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/master/code_samples/tool_window

Answer (score 0):

Actions should be registered this way (inside  in plugin.xml) :

```
    <actions>
    <group id="MyPlugin.TopMenu"
           text="_MyPlugin"
           description="MyPlugin Toolbar Menu">
        <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
        <action id="MyAction"
                class="actions.MyAction"
                text="_MyAction"
                description="MyAction"/>
    </group>
</actions>
```

Also, make sure your action is **inside a package**, otherwise it might not be found/called.